# Coded UI scripts fail when remote desktop minimized or locked

Tags: test-automation-framework, coded-ui-tests

I am using remote desktop to run my Coded UI scripts.

When I minimize remote desktop window or lock my PC test cases starts to fail.

Anyone had this problem?

Can you recommend some solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal for any GUI script. Minimizing or locking the PC causes Remote Desktop to discard the session window - I would guarantee the exceptions you get when the test cases fail involve no such element or something to the effect of there not being a screen to interact with.

The answer is not to use remote desktop. Coded UI doesn't work with headless browsers, so you need to run in a GUI session - I've found that setting up a VNC server on the test machine and using a VNC client to view what's happening is the best way because VNC hooks into the existing windowed environment rather than creating a windowed session.

You will need to use other methods to ensure your test run machine is online and logged in, but other than that, VNC won't cause your scripts to fail when you close the client.